# Is there any way to rewrite this select command in a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the select:

```
SELECT e.Id AS EmployeeId, 
ISNULL(
SUM(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) < 360 
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) < 560
        THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) - 20
    ELSE
        DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) - 45
    END), 0) AS OvertimeSum
FROM
    Overtimes o 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Employees e ON o.EmployeeId = e.Id
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.Id = e.GroupId
WHERE 
    (((CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) >= @StartDate) AND 
    (CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) <= @EndDate)) OR
    (o.StartDate IS NULL)) AND
    (g.ShiftModelId = @ShiftModelId)
GROUP BY e.Id
```

I think the select clause. It too long, for example is it possible to take `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate)` into a variable or something.

Comment: You might consider calculating the datediff in a with clause so that you only need to calculate it once. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As Joe W mentions in the comments, you can move the common datediff to a common expression to simplify things slightly, something like (the untested);

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT e.Id AS EmployeeId, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) Overtime
  FROM
    Overtimes o 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Employees e ON o.EmployeeId = e.Id
    INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.Id = e.GroupId
  WHERE 
    (((CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) >= @StartDate) AND 
      (CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) <= @EndDate)) OR
    (o.StartDate IS NULL)) AND
    (g.ShiftModelId = @ShiftModelId)
)
SELECT EmployeeId, ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Overtime < 360 THEN Overtime 
                                   WHEN Overtime < 560 THEN Overtime - 20
                                   ELSE                     Overtime - 45
                                   END), 0) AS OvertimeSum
FROM cte
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0):

couple of things.

divide the query and apply filters on individual tables before doing the JOIN when ever possible. update the datatype of Local Variable to match the data Type of Column in table. Using functions on Left side Column in WHERE condition is not good and Index will not be used for such queries. in you case that statement is:

CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) >= @StartDate

CONVERT(DATE, o.StartDate) <= @EndDate

instead update @StartDate as Datetime or whatever column type o.StartDate is. i see you need to compare only date and not time part so update/add your incoming local parameter value with Zero time part before using it in to query. same thing with @EndDate.

make sure you have Index on Overtimes.StartDate column. i am not sure what other indexes you have. or what other types of query you have against this table but

**if CLUSTERED Then (Overtimes.StartDate , Overtimes.EmployeeId)**

**If Covering Non-Clustered Then (Overtimes.StartDate) Include (EmployeeId)**

for table Employees and Groups make sure you have similar index.

**Clustered/NonClustered --> (Groups.ShiftModelId , Groups.ID) and  (Employees.GroupID)**

and then try this query

```
    SELECT EmployeeId,OvertimeSum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  o.EmployeeId AS EmployeeId ,
                ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) < 360
                                THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate)
                                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) < 560
                                THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) - 20
                                ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, o.StartDate, o.EndDate) - 45
                           END), 0) AS OvertimeSum
        FROM    Overtimes o
        WHERE ( o.StartDate IS NULL ) OR ( o.StartDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate )
        GROUP BY o.EmployeeId
    )q1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT e.ID AS EmployeeId
        FROM Employees e
        INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.Id = e.GroupId
        AND g.ShiftModelId = @ShiftModelId
    )q2
        ON q1.EmployeeId=q2.EmployeeId
```

Comment: Thank you for this response, are you sure that joining subselects is faster than joining tables? I always thought that the SQL Server optimizes it to make the join on filtered tables. And when you join subqueries, are you sure that the indexes are used when joining?

Comment: with all suggested changes, yes it will faster than the actual query you have written. and the reasons i already explain in my answer.

Comment: check the execution plan of your query, and then compare with the one I posted.

Comment: How does it compare to the query posted by Joachim Isaksson?

Comment: with CTE it is unpredictable. you need to try and see. but as some of the WHERE and JOIN clause changes I mentioned still applies. I doubt that with Function CONVERT in there in where clause the JOIN is efficient as it will not use indexes most efficient way. and because the OP is about performance issue i believe the data in theses table will be large enough and that why I said with CTE it is like Test and See.

Comment: @AnupShah There is an INNER JOIN. Why don't you separate that in a subselect like you did with the RIGHT OUTER JOIN? (Because it would have a where clause: g.ShiftModelId = @ShiftModelId) And to where would you do this in the subquery? In the q2 would you do a q2_1 and a q2_2 or it would be a q3? And please answer my first comment's question: Are you sure that joining subselects is faster than joining tables?

Comment: well doesn't seems like you have read the entire answer or if you read then missed the important piece. Dividing query means, we want to reduce the result set getting join as much as possible. I will not get any better data set to work with even if I divide INNER JOIN to sub queries. if you look at the two sub queries they are independent and optimizer will have much better dataset compare to joining all tables at same time. the advantage I need to take from Indexes is I already did in SubQuery. whatever that subquery returns is my final set so Index can't help me on RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: BTW, I did answer your question in previous comments. and again you might be concern right now with how fast query runs. but does query runs consistently fast is equally important. I would prefer if query takes bit more time but I will be assure that every time I run query optimizer will have good/consistent plan against the query give some time good performance and some time not good.

Comment: I read your entire answer. I'm not an SQL Server expert (this is why I ask). I understand why you think it's better join subqueries just always thought that the joins are automatically done with the reduced tables and your query is less readable then the original. But I don't say you are not right.